# Create mysql table from a query run on another PHP page

Tags: php, html, mysql, tabular

I have a PHP page that processes some information when a button is pressed. One of this information is to process a query. I then want the results of the query to be put into a table in another page. I know how to put query results into a table, but I don't know how to pass them row by row to a table on another page. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: why can't you query the information on one page and retrieve the information from another?

Comment: I dont know how I can pass it row by row...so the table on the other page would have the correct results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you'll need AJAX (and, by requirement, JavaScript) for this. What you want to do is call your generation function and have it return a format that you can parse (JSON, XML, you name it).

From there, you'll append it to your table using JavaScript's DOM manipulation functions.

**The generation part**

Assume that you're getting your data in an array format as follows:

```
$row = array('column 1','column2');
```

You'll be getting tons of rows like these, or just one - we'll write the script to handle both cases without requiring a rewrite. Every time you get a row, add it to a non-associative array , call it $RowArray. So, on every row, you'll be calling `$RowArray[] = $row;`.

You now have the PHP side almost done - all you need to do now is to echo it back to the client. Make sure you echo *nothing else* but this: `echo json_encode($RowArray);`. This will format and serialize your array to be a perfect JSON object.

**The JavaScript side**

We'll assume jQuery for simplicity. Your aim will be to read the JSON object and add rows to a table. We'll assume that the table has ID #MyTable.

The AJAX call is done as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_url.php",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "post",
  success: function(d) {
     // Your code here
  }
});
```

The `success` handler will be triggered when the object has been successfully parsed, and the variable `d` will be the object. This object will be a JavaScript array where each element is an object. All you need to do now is to loop through `d` and create a row per entry!

```
success: function(d) {
   for(var i=0; i < d.length; i++) {
      var newRow = $("<tr></tr");
      for (var k in d[i]) {
          newRow.append($("<td></td>").text(d[i][k]));
      }
      newRow.appendTo($("#MyTable"));
   }
}
```

Voila, dynamic AJAXified table in six lines!

Comment: I'll edit and flesh out my answer with code, then. Always good to check first.

Comment: There, fleshed out the answer greatly.